# diag() within norm expression (difference of matrices)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-equations

Im wondering whether this expression holds for all matrices

$$
||diag(A(X-Y))|| \le \lambda_{max}(diag(A))||diag(X-Y)||
$$

where diag is selecting only the diagonal entries of the matrix,
and $\lambda_{max}$ could be the maximum eigenvalue OR the maximum singular value

and would the following expression be wrong?

$$
||diag(A(X-Y))|| \le \lambda_{max}(A)||diag(X-Y)||
$$

^If this expression is not wrong, then I am guessing it would just give us a weaker (less tight) bound in comparison to the first expression right?

Thank you for taking the time, I really appreciate any help I could get!

Comment: It's hard to understand your question. What do you mean "diag is selecting only the diagonal entries of the matrix"? Do you mean that $\operatorname{diag}(M)$ is the matrix whose diagonal is the same as $M$ and all other entries are $0$ for any matrix $M$?

Comment: Also, there are many norms on matrices, which one do you mean?

Comment: $\lambda_{\textrm{max}}$ is the maximum eigenvalue ... of what? And how do you decide which eigenvalue is largest if some are complex?

Comment: Hi Joshua, thanks for your message. The norm is not specified so I am looking to see if this works for any norm. However, we are working only with matrices which have real eigenvalues, and yes we are dealing with the definition of diag(M) that you stated

Comment: Essentially this comes from me trying to find a lipschitz constant for the gradient of a function, so therefore I don't work with any specific norm, so thus I have to compute this constant with regards to any generalized norm right?

Comment: Could you explain more this link to a Lipschitz constant for the gradient of a function?

Comment: @JoshuaTilley I am applying MM algorithm to an objective function, and the surrogate upperbound I use to majorize and then minimize, has within its expression a Lipschitz constant L for the gradient of the function. ||gradf(theta1)-gradf(theta2)|| <= L||theta1-theta2|| but my algorithm doesn't use a specific norm so I assume I have to find an upperbound for this L, for any norm. The problem is that my gradient of the objective function is in terms of this diag() operator, so if I want to find a reasonable upperbound for L, I have to extract some maximum singular or eigen values in some steps.